# spring.config.import doesn't accept configserver option when in yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a bunch of services and recently migrated to new Spring Boot/Cloud. All but one works ok. The one complains like this:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Config data location 'configserver:http://localhost:8888/' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'configserver:http://localhost:8888/' at class path resource [application.yaml] - 5:13 is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'
```

Making it optional makes service to completely skip remote configuration. Other services tells

```
Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888/
```

but this one misses it completely.
I've checked dependencies, they looks ok, tried to use latest spring-cloud-starter-config 3.0.5 but didn't change anything.

application.yaml looks like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: some-service
  config:
    import: "configserver:http://localhost:8888/"
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        max-attempts: 5000
        initial-interval: 1500
        multiplier: 1.5
```

All services has exactly the same config, just different names.
I have also another service which had similar problem, and switching from application.yaml to application.properties has fixed the problem. I don't like this solution, that's why I'm asking for help here. I suppose I miss some dependency or it has different version. I've even found similar problem, but no solution is visible: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1933

Edit: I've switched from yaml to properties format and it's working ok. Why yaml is not working?

Comment: your yaml is formatted incorrectly. Is that exactly what you have (cloud is nested under spring.application.name, not spring)?

Comment: no, it's a problem of stackoverfow formatting

Answer (score -1):

So the problem was excessive application.properties in one of attached library. After removing this properties everything is working as expected.
Probably something in Spring Boot doesn't like such additional properties.